# Click handler not firing on position: fixed; in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm creating a substitute for a `<select />` element, which is working pretty well - even in Firefox. Long story short, I create a list of `<div class="option">`, and add a click listener to each of those, that handles setting the correct selected value etc etc.

However, if the list is too long to display on the screen, I switch the `position` of the container element of my options from `absolute` to `fixed`.

Suddenly, in Firefox 45, the click handlers for my options are not being fired. Works perfectly in both Chrome and Safari and IE.

Any idea as to why?

[Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/zqNgyG) with all my code (there's a lot of it). It works for some reason when I remove the surrounding divs for each element, but not with them.

The code that's not being fired is the following in the `_initEvents()` method:

```
this.$options.forEach((option, index) => {
    option.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log('this never fires');
        this.currentIndex = index;
        this._changeOption();
        this._toggleDropdown();
    });
});
```

Edit: Adding `html, body { height: 100% }` fixes the problem on CodePen, but not in my site. Any idea why?

Edit 2: Turns out it works... sometimes. But it's buggy as hell - it selects the wrong option and what not.

Comment: Can you supply a link or a portion of the code that replicates the issue?

Comment: @Garconis - added a link now. Sorry for the sheer amount of code.